# How to serialize Java Calendar and Java Date to Javascript Date

Tags: java, javascript, json, jackson

I want to serialize from Java to JSON objects Java Calendar and Java Date to Javascript Date.

I want that in Javascript, the variable Javascript Date without having to do the "eval" or "new Date" has a Date value.

I tried to return "new Date (timeInMiliseconds)" but I obtained, obviously a 'String'I. I know I can do "eval" to this "String" but I wan't do it.
I have also tried to return "miliseconds" and in "Javascript" call "new Date ()", But I do not want to do that.

The JSON currently looks like

```
 {hours:[
   {date:'new Date(1)', color:'fff'},
   {date:'new Date(2)', color: 'ddd'}, 
   ... ]}
```

Any suggestions?

Info: I'm using Spring MVC and Jackson to serialize.

---

**Edit#1:**

I know this methods:

**Java Return** ----------------------- **Javascript**

"new Date(100000)" ------------- var myDate = eval("new Date(100000)");

100000 ------------------------------  var myDate = new Date(10000);

But I'm searching the format that indicate to the client side parsers that the data fragment that was sent is a date representation. 
But how can you convert it to a JavaScript Date object?

Comment: What was the problem with `new Date (timeInMiliseconds)`  ?

Comment: @mplungjan The problem is that Java return String, and I don't like do eval.

Comment: @mplungjan Ok. If I try that Java return for each var date is "new Date(miliseconds)". In Javascript, I need do "eval" each String var for get Javscript Date.

Comment: @mplungjan The output is from Server Controller to a jQuery plugin that read the json.

Comment: And how does the JSON look exactly?

Comment: @mplungjan Now the JSON look: {hours:[{date:'new Date(1)', color:'fff'},{data:'new Date(2)', color: 'ddd'}, ... ]}.

Comment: instead have {hours:[{date:1638721368, color:'fff'},{data:9874587345, color: 'ddd'} - having code in JSON does not make any sense

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, I could return the time in milis but in this case I need do "new Date" in Javascript.

Comment: I fail to see why. SINCE you **DO** need to use `eval` to execute it, then you are better off and will save data if you just send the timestamp. A horrible alternative is to do object.date=new Date(object.date.replace(/[^\d]/g,""))

Comment: @mplungjan. Yes, I know that the best option is return the time in miliseconds. But I'm searching a way for in client side have the date without do "eval" or "new Date". For example with a directive

Comment: See my answer. What directive do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.

You cannot parse a string with `date: "new date(123434534)"` without `eval` or `new Date(extracted timestamp)` like this

```
object.date=new Date(object.date.replace(/[^\d]/g,""));
```

I still fail to see **why** you need to  pass a string of `"new Date(timestamp)"`

You are better off and will save data if you just send the timestamp.

Comment: I'm passing a string of "new Date(timestamp)" for trying found a solution. I know that is it a bad idea and thet best solution is return time in milis. So the problem is that I  would like that in the client side have a date without do "eval" or "new Date"

Comment: As I answered: Not possible